# Automatic configuration of ssrs with power shell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

i have already installed Report server database. I know how to configure Report server through RS Configuration Manager, but i want to do this automatically with power shell.
So how to change these thing:

1. Change data source connection string
2. Backup and restore encryption key (i will have Report server on two instances and will have RS in sync)
3. Change rsconfig file (modify Authentication types, add 2 more for Kerberos)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Get-WMIObject with the configuration settings for the SSRS 2017 instance and then setting the required configuration

```
Get-WmiObject –namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_SSRS\v14\Admin" -class MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting -ComputerName localhost
```

connect to the machine

```
    $conn = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection -ArgumentList $env:ComputerName
    $conn.ApplicationName = "SSRS Configuration Script"
    $conn.StatementTimeout = 0
    $conn.Connect()
    $smo = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $conn
```

and change the configuration as required

```
## Create the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases
$db = $smo.Databases["master"]
$db.ExecuteNonQuery($dbscript)

## Set permissions for the databases
$dbscript = $configset.GenerateDatabaseRightsScript($configset.WindowsServiceIdentityConfigured, "ReportServer", $false, $true).Script
$db.ExecuteNonQuery($dbscript)

## Set the database connection info
$configset.SetDatabaseConnection("(local)", "ReportServer", 2, "", "")
```

You can modify the script for other two things #2 & #3. Refer [this article](https://blog.aelterman.com/2018/01/03/complete-automated-configuration-of-sql-server-2017-reporting-services/) for more details. hope that should help.